# What can an attacker do if he has access to my wp-config file?

Tags: wp-config

Can he do anything 
besides read database connection which is localhost
and not accessible via remote host ?

Comment: What's the context behind this, and what do you mean by access? Are we talking read access? write access? both? Or do you mean just going to `example.com/wp-config.php` in a browser?

Comment: Read access, to be able to read the wp-config contents
I had a wp-config.txt backup and I saw it was ccessed via access logs

Comment: At the risk of committing what my daughter would refer to as "mansplaining," the most important thing to do immediately would be to change your DB credentials - I hope you've already done that.

Comment: and reset all passwords, if your secret hashes/salts are exposed then that's a problem too

Comment: he can get access to my wp-admin credentials?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, are the credentials inside wp-config.txt for your live website? Or just a previous local version? If it's just your local version, then no, there's nothing they can do.

Comment: live site
they have db credentials connecting localhost

Answer (score 0):

`wp-config.php` is an important file of the WP installation. It acts as a bridge between the WP file system and the MySQL database. `wp-config.php` contains the database connection credentials. Apart from this, it can also be used for:

- Defining the security keys.
- To specify the database prefix.
- To set the default language for your admin panel.

If you have been hacked I recommend looking at: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked